# Minimum supported Android version Cordova 9

Tags: android, cordova

What is the minimum supported android version/API for Cordova 9.x?

the website only mentions up until 8.x:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/platforms/android/platforms/android/build.gradle` reads:

```
defaultMinSdkVersion=19
```

Currently, it doesn't even seem stable; see [milestone 2](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/milestone/2): `92% complete`.

Answer (score 1):

cordova-android 9 has not been released yet, you probably mean Cordova CLI 9.

Cordova CLI 9 installs cordova-android 8 (but you can install older versions too). The table you linked is for cordova-android, that's why it only goes up to version 8, will be updated once version 9 is released.

cordova-android 8 supports SDK 19+

cordova-android 9 will support SDK 22+